# Excel VBA fill empty columns on left with data from right, varying number of filled columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I think I'm too dumb to explain this so here's an example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 121 |  | 221 |  | 335 | 335 |  | 558 | 669 |  | 126 |
| 2 |  | 54 |  | 89 |  | 56 |  |  | 78 |  |  | 23 |
| 3 |  | 85 |  |  |  |  | 59 |  |  | 16 |  | 15 |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  | 16 |  | 95 |  | 48 | 16 |  |  | 79 |  | 16 |

So this is what the sheet look like. What I would like is for:

For all columns that have the same value in row 1 i.e. 121,221, 335

-get the value in those columns and add them together in the column that precedes the column with the first value in Row A

For example,
the first column in this table will have the sum of B2 in row A2
H3 will be the sum of I3+J3
E5 will be the sum of F5+G5

Finally, the blank columns will take the row 1 value of the columns pulled from
-A1 will = B1
-C1 will = D1

Then all originally filled columns will be deleted:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 | 221 | 335 | 558 | 669 | 126 |
| 2 | 54 | 89 | 56 | 78 | 0 | 23 |
| 3 | 85 | 0 | 59 | 0 | 16 | 15 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 16 | 95 | 64 | 0 | 79 | 16 |

There is no pattern to the values in row 1

Thanks for any help you can provide, I've made some progress on this project but this has me stumped.

Comment: You say _I've made some progress on this project but this has me stumped_ so show us what you've got, and what's stopping you progressing.   As written this sounds like a "do my work for me" request, which is unlikely to be answered

Comment: I meant that I have gotten to this stage, there were other steps before that I completed and do not need help with. I just need a way to complete what's described. I'm sorry if I have poor etiquette. This is my first time using VBA

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithmic approach you can use

1. Get a Reference to your source data range
2. Copy that range to a Variant Array
3. Create another empty array same size as the data
4. Create a column pointer variable for output
5. Initialize the first column of the output array to 0
6. Loop the first row of the data
7. When a value is found, check if it's the same as the value in the current Output column
8. If it's not, update output pointer, Initialize the new column to 0
9. Loop the data column and add the values to the output column
10. Once the loop is complete, place the output array on the sheet, overwriting the original data

There are plenty of answers on SO that can help with each of these steps

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. I’ll give it a try and report back.